# Exception in delivering result of invoking method - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

my Server side code

```
 Meteor.methods({
  'doCount': function(){
      var x = ProductList.find().count();
      console.log(x);
      return x;
  }
});
```

and My client side code is

```
Meteor.call('doCount', function(error, result) {

    console.log("lenght of counters variable is "+counters.length);
    var queryResult = ProductList.find().fetch();
    for(i=0 ; i< result; i++){
        console.log("current Time >>> "+ TimeSync.serverTime();
        console.log("expire Time "+ queryResult[i].expire);
          }

});
```

Though chrome browser is returning the correct log everytime. Firefox is behaving in Strange way. here's the screenshot

[image: Error showing in Firefox console]

And i'm also using [meteor-timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync) package for `TimeSync.serverTime()` function call.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're counting on the server and fetching the items inside `ProductList` client-side? Also what happens when you comment out the `TimeSync.serverTime();` part?

Comment: well, i'm trying to prototype a penny-auction app. so I need how many products are currently running in the auction and according to that I need that many countdown timer to run offline.

Comment: But why don't you call `ProductList.find().count();` client-side? Your code is implying that all `ProductList`s documents are public. (`var queryResult = ProductList.find().fetch();` ... `queryResult[i]`)

Comment: If I do that you suggested, that's still not gonna solve my problem i guess. I'm having trouble in getting the `TimeSync.serverTime()` value

Comment: So you are saying that `TimeSync.serverTime()` doesn't work in FF? Did you try running it from the FF dev console?

Comment: Yes, i tried in the FF dev console. And the screenshot is from it's console output.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page here... Did you paste just the function call `TimeSync.serverTime()` into the command prompt at the very bottom of the console and press enter?

Comment: never mind, the problem is solved. The problem actually was with FF. Server time was not syncing properly. So I put the syncing code in  `Meter.startup`